# "show 20 more messages" button in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button, email, inbox

I am newbie to iphone programming. I doing an mail like app in that i have to show inbox information in table view and at the final of dragging i should need "show 20 more messages" button. is there possibility of showing that?

if please can you provide with me a codes.

Regards,
sathish

Comment: Stack overflow isn't site for spoon feeding for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to manage it manually:

1. Add one extra row to your table view.
2. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, if the `indexPath` corresponds to the last possible row (which is the extra row you added), create a cell that represents the button.
3. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, if the `indexPath` corresponds to the last possible row, have your datasource load the additional data and send a `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to your table view.

Comment: thanks ole? can i have code for it. sorrry for asking i am newbie to iphone

Comment: I don't have code for this and if I had, I probably wouldn't post it here because it doesn't make sense. The specific implementation depends on your app and you should really do this yourself anyway, if only for the learning experience.